# How to connect to PCF from java app and list orgs, spaces, apps and their configuration?

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to connect to PCF from java application. Code available in [github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) helped connecting to PCF. Is there any class or dependency which allows user to connect to PCF using Rest API calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CF Java Client is exactly what you're requesting. It has methods available to query orgs, spaces, apps and anything you can get via the Cloud Foundry API.

You will most likely want to start with CloudFoundryOperations as that is higher level and maps more to Cloud Foundry concepts.

Here's an example [from the docs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloudfoundryoperations-apis) that shows how to fetch all the orgs.

```
cloudFoundryOperations.organizations()
    .list()
    .map(OrganizationSummary::getName)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

There are more examples in the [integration tests here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/tree/master/integration-test/src/test/java/org/cloudfoundry/operations).

You can use a [CloudFoundryClient](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloudfoundryclient-apis) if you want slightly lower level access. This maps more directly onto the API itself. There are [examples of using this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/tree/master/integration-test/src/test/java/org/cloudfoundry/client) in the integration tests as well.

There are also Javadoc links, if you want to drill down into the API.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloud-foundry-java-client

Hope that helps!